# How to pass the name of the image as a parameter?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql, ajax

There is something I am trying to acheive but I don't quite understand how to do it. What I think I need to do is to pass the name of the image as a parameter to the cancelimage.php script and the use that in the query. But I don't think I am doing this with var image_file_name. What do I need to do to achieve this?

Below is the startImageUpload() function where it starts uploading an image and where the cancel button exist:

```
 function startImageUpload(imageuploadform){

    ...

                $(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {

var image_file_name = $(this).attr('image_file_name');

                jQuery.ajax("cancelimage.php"  + image_file_name)
                    .done(function(data) {

                    $(".imagemsg" + _cancelimagecounter).html(data);
                });

                return stopImageUpload();

            });       
                  return true;
            }
```

Below is the cancelimage,php page where it is suppose to delete a row from the database?

```
<?php

$username="xxx";
$password="xxx";
$database="xxx";

mysql_connect('localhost',$username,$password);

mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

$image_file_name = $_GET["fileImage"]["name"];

    echo "File Upload was Canceled";

        $imagecancelsql = "DELETE FROM Image 
        WHERE ImageFile = 'ImageFiles/". mysql_real_escape_string($image_file_name)."'";

    mysql_query($imagecancelsql);

    mysql_close();


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If that is the issue with only variable passed with "image_file_name", then why dont your try to achieve it like this:

```
var image_file_name = "<?php echo $image_file_name; ?>"
```

Then you can just forward it as url to ajax call like in regular mannar:

```
       jQuery.ajax("cancelimage.php"  + image_file_name)
                    .done(function(data) {
                   .....some code here....

    });
```

Comment: It is giving me a unterminated string literal errro for var image_file_name?

Comment: just try to put semicolon at the end of the variable like `var image_file_name = "<?php echo $image_file_name; ?>";`

Comment: I did already put the semi colon but same problem. The error it is showing is this: unterminated string literal: `var image_file_name = "<br />`

Comment: Obviously you need to ensure that all linebreaks and single quotes in that string are escaped (\n and \').So you can make a function that can ignore this by  `preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', null, $image_file_name)` .Well, in the case it does help you, make it an answer

Comment: I have tried this and it is still causing the error. This is a stupid error

Comment: the only problem is with `"<br />` . the `/` is producing the concerned error.Try making something that does not output `"<br />` in the variable.

Comment: @user1373827 and also while passing the file name pass it this way `jQuery.ajax("cancelimage.php?imageFileName="  + image_file_name)` and GET it as `$_GET['imageFileName']`